# Jasmine and importing a custom node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, electron

I've been trying to use Jasmine to test my code which has worked fine until I needed to test code that used a custom Node addon.  I'm requiring the addon in the typical way,

```
var addon = require('../build/Release/addon.node');
```

which works totally fine while running the application, but Jasmine chokes on it, spitting out:

```
Error: The specified module could not be found.
```

Is there a way to tell Jasmine where to find the required modules?

Answer (score 1):

Use `__dirname + "/../path/to file"` - https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname

Comment: That gives the correct path, but Jasmine still returns "The specified module could not be found."  
I'm wondering if this is an issue with using custom node addons, files with the .node extension.